# Trigger based on sysdate

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE CHARGES 
(
    total NUMBER(30),
    admitdate TIMESTAMP(6),
    dischargedate TIMESTAMP(30)
)
```

Trigger Algorithm:

```
if 
{
   dischargedate="null" 
   then total=admitdate-sysdate=difference in days * Total
   Do this every day at 12:00(24 Hr. Format)
}
else
{
    Do Nothing;
}
```

My question is what to do if the system is offline at 12:00 am. This problem will not allow the trigger to run.

Answer (score 1):

To run a piece of code on a specific time, you can use *jobs*. Triggers are there only to respond to table changes. 
If the server is down (which it should hardly ever be), the job can be run at a later time.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about jobs thanks for letting me know i will try this with jobs

Comment: but if the system is offline at 12:00 how can we check if the job is executed or not, after the system regains control and becomes online

Comment: @Akki for dbms_scheduler jobs check [ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2048.htm#i1587156) and [ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2047.htm) views for job details. they will "catch up" if the scheduled time was missed due to down time. for the older DBMS_JOB, there's less logging but last date etc are listed in [ALL_JOBS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1086.htm#i1580430)

Comment: SELECT to_char(sysdate,DD-MON-YY),job_name,operation,status FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG WHERE job_name="your job name" AND status="SUCCEEDED"
if not found then rerun the job is it right @DazzaL

Comment: @Akki that table is a log table, so it will have many rows (1 for each run). so you need to look at the `REQ_START_DATE` of interest

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to maintain and reason about if you can change approach and store only static values.And do calculations using sysdate only when needed, like in sql output when asked for it.

Comment: The project i am making is dynamic i need to perform these task everyday at 12:00 but need  to plan about disaster also that's why thinking what if system becomes down