# Events based on sysdate

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trigger based on sysdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110433/trigger-based-on-sysdate)

1.I have a table on which i have to perform update operations everyday at 12:00(24 Hr. Format).

How should I accomplish this?

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE CHARGES   
(
    total NUMBER(30),
    admitdate TIMESTAMP(6),
    dischargedate TIMESTAMP(30)
)
```

Update Algorithm:

```
if 
{
   dischargedate="null" 
   then total=admitdate-sysdate=difference in days * Total
   Do this every day at 12:00(24 Hr. Format)
}
else
{  
  do nothing.    
}
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110433/trigger-based-on-sysdate)?

Comment: this is not clear: `then total=admitdate-sysdate=difference in days * Total`

Comment: Can't you just run a (for example PHP) script every day? With the PHP CLI that shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: In previous question it was based on trigger what if triggers doesn't runs as the system goes offline but i think the trigger will not be working for this algorithm so need some help on accomplishing this task.  @Mat

Comment: It is the number of difference between two dates * total @codingbiz

Comment: @11684          I want it to run automatically not manually

Comment: @Akki that's easily possible with CLI. I'll post an alternative answer tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, @Akki, I forgot and now it's closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard to run a job every 24 hours would be to run a job at this interval using the system package [`DBMS_SCHEDULER`](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?remark=quick_search&word=dbms_scheduler).

For instance:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'update_charges',
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'BEGIN my_procedure; END;',
    start_date      => TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 0.5,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily;',
    end_date        => NULL,
    enabled         => TRUE,
    comments        => 'Update the discharged date in charges.');
END;
/
```

You then create a procedure to run:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE my_procedure is

begin

  update charges
     set total = admitdate - sysdate
   where dischargedate is null;

end;
/
```

This would update the column total to be the number of days between the `admitdate` and SYSDATE.

**However**, I question the need to do this at all. It sounds very much like the age-old "Should I store Age" question. [I believe the answer is no.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788542/how-to-store-birthdate-and-age-so-that-age-can-be-updated-daily-in-php-mysql/9788624#9788624) You are absolutely bound to be wrong at some point and there are a number of possibilities that might cause the job to be manually run incorrectly. I would calculate this column on the fly as you extract data from the database.

Comment: +1, for mentioning the entire concept of storing age.

Comment: @Ben              Will this job get executed everyday and if everyday than at what time

Comment: This should execute at midday (the `+0.5` part) and be executed daily (`freq=daily`). I would highly recommend reading the linked documentation though. It's quite complicated so looking at [some examples](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php) may be helpful as well...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have a built in scheduler. There a few different ways to tackle this. Here are two:

1) Create a sql script that is run through the scheduling mechanism of your server. For Unix/Linux this will be a cron job. For Windows this will be a Scheduled Task.

2) Create a scheduled job using the CREATE_JOB syntax:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name           =>  'update_charges',
    job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action         =>  'MYSCHEMA.SOME_PKG.UPDATE_CHARGES',
    start_date         =>  '28-APR-08 12.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
    repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1', /* every other day */
    end_date           =>  '20-NOV-13 12.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
    job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
    comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
```

Comment: Sorry,yes but what if system is offline at 12:00 @davidethell

Comment: If the system is offline at 12:00 @Akki, you're pure out of luck, that's why I suggest _not_ storing this column at all.

Comment: @Akki, if you are scheduling a daily job at 12PM then it is the server admin's job to be sure the server is online.

Comment: thanks for replying and answering @davidethell

Answer (score 0):

Expressed as SQL, I think your algorithm is implemented in the `UPDATE` statement below. You seem to want to multiply `total` by itself each time your algorithm runs; I'm assuming that's my misunderstanding or your typo. It seems to make more sense that `total` simply equals the difference between the admit date and the current date.

```
UPDATE CHARGES
   SET Total = DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), AdmitDate)
 WHERE DischargeDate IS NULL;
```

To make sure this query runs efficiently, you'll want to have an index over the `DischargeDate` column.

To do this every day at a certain time, you have a few choices.

One approach, if you have your own server code running of your own, is to have that code schedule the work and execute it whenever you'd like. If you have good monitoring and management built into your server-side architecture.

Another approach is to run a `chron` or `at` job, depending on which OSes you're using.

Comment: I think OP tagged it `ORACLE`??/

Comment: OP means Original Post/Poster. In this context, it is the person that asked the question.